# TypeError: off is not a from solanaWalletAdapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, typescript, nextjs

I am getting this error in next.js

[image]

thats my index.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import { UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import {
  WalletModalProvider,
  WalletDisconnectButton,
  WalletMultiButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { SendSOLToRandomAddress } from '../components/button';

// Default styles that can be overridden by your app
require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

export default function Wallet() {
  // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
  const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

  // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
  const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

  const wallets = useMemo(
    () => [
      /**
       * Wallets that implement either of these standards will be available automatically.
       *
       *   - Solana Mobile Stack Mobile Wallet Adapter Protocol
       *     (https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter)
       *   - Solana Wallet Standard
       *     (https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-standard)
       *
       * If you wish to support a wallet that supports neither of those standards,
       * instantiate its legacy wallet adapter here. Common legacy adapters can be found
       * in the npm package `@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets`.
       */
      //new UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter(),
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [network]
  );

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          <WalletMultiButton />
          <WalletDisconnectButton />
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <SendSOLToRandomAddress />
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
};
```

I was using these docs as reference https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. Can you please file this as a _bug report_ on Github. List the wallet adapters that you are using _and_ the wallets installed on your system. https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this when using the OKX wallet. Removing/disabling the wallet the issue is fixed.